# Save logging.debug in a variable or send it one-by-one

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, pyrogram

I want to save the `logging` data just as it shows them in the console one-by-one, in a variable (one error per exception, then rewrite the variable with the new one) so I can send it to the user's chat (in Pyrogram) on every new log...
something like this:

```py
try:
    func()
except Exception as e:
    errlog =  logging.debug("Error", exc_info=True)
    app.send.message(chat_id=1, text=errlog)
```

I've also tried the above code by iterating through the `logging.debug` (which indicates I know nothing about how to handle it!)...
I just know I should write my own handler but I don't know how to do that (send **every log at the defined level** one-by-one outside of the console or local file).
tried [this link](http://alanwsmith.com/capturing-python-log-output-in-a-variable) (below code) but it didn't work...

```py
except Exception as e:
    logger = logging.getLogger('basic_logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_capture_string = io.StringIO()
    ch = logging.StreamHandler(log_capture_string)
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(" %(asctime)s  ⚠ #%(levelname)s   %(message)s",
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.debug('DEBUG', exc_info=True)
    logger.info('INFO', exc_info=True)
    logger.warn('WARN', exc_info=True)
    logger.error('ERROR', exc_info=True)
    logger.critical('CRITICAL', exc_info=True)
    LogErr = log_capture_string.getvalue()
    app.send_message(chat_id=LogGpID, text=LogErr)
```

In other words, I want to get all these messages as a variable into the `text` parameter of the `send_message` upon it appearing on the console.[image: ...]
what should I do to achieve that?

Comment: provide a [mre], `logging` also logs the logs one by one so elaborate a bit more on your issue (you can [edit] your question to include the info)

Comment: You have to write a Handler and attach it to the Logger.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks but I don't know how to write it...

Comment: Read the [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) and Cookbook!

Comment: @KlausD. thanks again, but I'm new to `logging` and there are so many methods and parameters here, I've searched and struggled on docs before I ask this question, I didn't find the solution or I didn't understand that... recommending to reading the whole doc will not solve my problem, could you please specify the section?